# What is different let ( without mut ) with const

Tags: rust

what's different let and const in rust ?
for example if use let without mut, is not possible change value

```rust
fn main(){
      let MYINT = 1;
      MYINT = 2; // error 

      const MYINT_ = 1;
      MYINT_ = 1; //error
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const` indicates a *compile-time constant* which means it can only be set to a value that can be computed at compile time, e.g. a literal or the result of calling a `const fn`.

`let` (without `mut`) indicates a *run-time constant* which means it can be initialized from the result of any valid expression.

As to the difference in behavior of the two, you can use `const` variables in contexts that require compile-time evaluation, such as the length of arrays.  You cannot use `let` variables in these contexts.  For example:

```
fn main() {
    const x: usize = 5;
    let x_arr = [0i32; x];
}
```

This compiles successfully, and `x_arr` has type `[i32; 5]`.

```
fn main() {
    let x: usize = 5;
    let x_arr = [0; x]; // E0435
}
```

This fails to compile; `x` cannot be used as an array length as the value must be known at compile time, and `x` is not a compile-time constant.

```
error[E0435]: attempt to use a non-constant value in a constant
```